# Unable to reproduce Numpy style indexing in MATLAB

Tags: python, matlab, numpy

Here's the Python code I'm trying to reproduce in MATLAB.

```
>>> M = np.zeros((5,5))
>>> indices = np.arange(5)
>>> M[indices[:-1], indices[:-1]+1] = 1
>>> print(M)
[[0. 1. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 1. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 1. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 1.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]]
```

Here's what happens when I write it in MATLAB.

```
>> M = zeros(5);
>> indices = 1:5;
>> M(indices(1:end-1), indices(1:end-1)+1) = 1
>>
M =

     0     1     1     1     1
     0     1     1     1     1
     0     1     1     1     1
     0     1     1     1     1
     0     0     0     0     0
```

How can I achieve the same indexing effect in MATLAB?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

MATLAB 2D indexing extracts a rectangular submatrix that its rows and columns are reordered based on the provided index vectors. But if you have a list of rows and columns and want to extract the corresponding elements you should convert 2D index to linear index and for it you can use [sub2ind](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/sub2ind.html):

```
M = zeros(5);
indices = 1:5;
idx = sub2ind([5,5],indices(1:end-1), indices(1:end-1)+1);
M(idx) = 1
```

Alternatively you can directly use linear indexing:

```
M = zeros(5);
M(5+1:5+1:end) = 1
```

How does linear indexing work?
In MATLAB  data are stored in column major format:

```
1    6   11   16   21
2    7   12   17   22
3    8   13   18   23
4    9   14   19   24
5   10   15   20   25
```

When you use the range `6:6:end` it means that you want  starting form element 6 with the step size 6 to extract elements so you want the elements `[6   12   18   24]`. This indexing scheme can be extended to ND arrays and non square matrices.

Comment: Thanks! Do you mind describing how your linear indexing method works?

Comment: Also, how would you extend this to non-square matrices? For example `M = zeros(4,3)`. I would expect the `1` to be at (1,1), (2,2), and (3,3)

Comment: Answer updated! For `zeros(4,3)` you can use `M(1:4+1:end)=1`.

Comment: Thanks! I think I get the hang of it.

Comment: Happy  to help.!